# Why can't AVR interrupt vectors be '__attribute__((weak))'?

Tags: interrupt, avr-gcc

I have just tried to add `__attribute__ ((weak))` to one of my interrupt handler definitions and I notice the vector jump is not implemented — the interrupt body appears in the compiled binary though.

Example, with "weak" interrupt:

```
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect, __attribute__ ((weak)))
{
    // some compiled code
    ...
}
```

Resulting assembly code — no jump:

```
    00000000 <__vectors>:
       0:   48 c0           rjmp    .+144           ; 0x92 <__ctors_end>
       4:   92 c0           rjmp    .+292           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
       8:   90 c0           rjmp    .+288           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
       c:   8e c0           rjmp    .+284           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      10:   8c c0           rjmp    .+280           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      14:   8a c0           rjmp    .+276           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      18:   88 c0           rjmp    .+272           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      1c:   86 c0           rjmp    .+268           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      20:   84 c0           rjmp    .+264           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      24:   82 c0           rjmp    .+260           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      28:   80 c0           rjmp    .+256           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      2c:   7e c0           rjmp    .+252           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      30:   7c c0           rjmp    .+248           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      34:   7a c0           rjmp    .+244           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      38:   78 c0           rjmp    .+240           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      3c:   76 c0           rjmp    .+236           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      40:   74 c0           rjmp    .+232           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      44:   72 c0           rjmp    .+228           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      48:   70 c0           rjmp    .+224           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      4c:   6e c0           rjmp    .+220           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      50:   6c c0           rjmp    .+216           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      54:   6a c0           rjmp    .+212           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      58:   68 c0           rjmp    .+208           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      5c:   66 c0           rjmp    .+204           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      60:   64 c0           rjmp    .+200           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      64:   62 c0           rjmp    .+196           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      68:   60 c0           rjmp    .+192           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      6c:   5e c0           rjmp    .+188           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
```

Now without the `weak` attribute:

```
    00000000 <__vectors>:
       0:   48 c0           rjmp    .+144           ; 0x92 <__ctors_end>
       4:   92 c0           rjmp    .+292           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
       8:   90 c0           rjmp    .+288           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
       c:   8e c0           rjmp    .+284           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      10:   8c c0           rjmp    .+280           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      14:   8a c0           rjmp    .+276           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      18:   88 c0           rjmp    .+272           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      1c:   29 c0           rjmp    .+82            ; 0x70 <__vector_7>
      20:   84 c0           rjmp    .+264           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      24:   82 c0           rjmp    .+260           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      28:   80 c0           rjmp    .+256           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>
      2c:   7e c0           rjmp    .+252           ; 0x12a <__bad_interrupt>

            ...
```

Is this a bug in `avr-gcc` (I have tried versions **5.3.x** and **7.1.0**) or have I missed something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`avr-libc` implements the ISR vector table using weak symbols. Then your code can define the proper symbol as non-weak to override the default ISR handler `__bad_interrupt` (cf. [`crt1/gcrt1.S`](https://github.com/avrdudes/avr-libc/blob/main/crt1/gcrt1.S) in the [`avr-libc` source code](https://github.com/avrdudes/avr-libc)).

So only a non-weak ISR symbol will override the weak default handler ISR symbol from `avr-libc`.

You might consider having your non-weak symbol ISR call a weak symbol function if you need that overridability and can afford to spend the additional cycles and stack space required for the call.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I have checked the source file. That explains it all.